# Does there exists a function $ \ f(z) \in \mathbb{C} \ $ such that

Tags: integration

Does there exists a function $ \ f(z) \in \mathbb{C} \ $ such that $ \ \lim_{z \to 0^{+}} f(z)=\infty \ $  but $ \ \int_{0}^{1} f(z) dz < \infty \ $ ?

If exists then give an example otherwise state why not exists.

**Answer:**

I think there does not exists such functions.

Because ,

$ \ \lim_{z \to 0^{+}} f(z)=\infty \ \Rightarrow f(z) \ \ is \ undefined \ \ as \ \ z \to 0^{+} $

Thus the integral $ \ \ \int_{0}^{1} f(z) dz  \to \infty \ $

**But I am not sure.**

**Help me out.**

Comment: The integral of a complex function is a complex number, when do you say that $c<\infty$ when $c$ is complex? Moreover, what is $\int_{0}^1$ when $\text{dom}(f)\subset \mathbb{C}$? You are probably looking at a real valued function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: No it can be complex valued function too

Comment: Again, in that case the integral is a complex number. There is no ordering on the complex numbers compatible with the field structure. So what does $c<\infty$ mean? It doesn't make sense!

Comment: we have to show that the integral is $ \ finite $

Comment: When is a complex number $c$ finite, if $|c|<\infty$? You are using awful terminology here. The answer below used correct terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x \in (0,1]$. Then $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)=\infty$, but the improper integral $ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx $ is convergent.